# How do I put a header in an api request in fact redux-saga?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I want to put a token in the header in mypage api request.
I'm using a function called createRequestSaga when I request api.

```
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { startLoading, finishLoading } from '../modules/loading';

export default function createRequestSaga(type, request) {
    const SUCECSS = `${type}_SUCCESS`;
    const FAILURE = `${type}_FAILURE`;

    return function* (action) {
        yield put(startLoading(type));  // START LOADING
        try {
            const response = yield call(request, action.payload);
            yield put({
                type: SUCECSS,
                payload: response.data,
            });
        } catch (e) {
            yield put({
                type: FAILURE,
                payload: e,
                error: true,
            });
        }
        yield put(finishLoading(type)); // FINISH LOADING
    };
}
```

This is api specification

[image: API Specification]

and in my container, I know how to send a variable in the request body,
like this :  dispatch(registerPost({ id, password, nickname, email, team }));
but I don't know how to send a token in the header.

Comment: I think this should be the responsibility of `request ` function and not redux-saga. Redux-saga *just* call this network function. The network function should add the token in the headers. What library are you using for your requests? Axios? Superagent?

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = yield call(
    rsf.functions.call,
    'sayHello',
    {
      name: 'Elon'
    },
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer abc123'
      }
    }
  );
```

This worked for me.

ref - https://redux-saga-firebase.js.org/reference/dev/functions